# Jquery Xdsoft Datetimepicker gets the seconds of the computer when added to Format

Tags: jquery

Hi Im new to Jquery Xdsoft datetimepicker and my question is why is my textbox and datetime picker populated with the seconds in my Clock whenever it loads.

Here is my Code snippet for my datetimepicker

```
$('#RunSendDate').datetimepicker(
    {
       step: 30,
       minDate: 0,
       minTime: 0,
       formatTime: 'h:i:s A',
       format: 'm/d/Y h:i A',
       lang: 'en',
   });
```

The output in my database is always `02/11/2016 1:30:24 PM`
and when I tried to look in my Computers Clock and Reload the page, the seconds is passed.

Answer (score 0):

I Get it , because of the property `minTime:0` that gets the minimum time of the day, It is returning and get the value of the Seconds in my Computer Clock